# prepareForSegue called before IBAction

Tags: uiimageview, swift, ibaction, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have `UIImageView` with `UITapGestureRecognizer`.
I want send to another VC some info when image is tapped. But code in `prepareForSegue` called before any `IBAction` (`UITapGestureRecognizer`) so I can't put any data in vars in `prepareForSegue`. How I can do that?

So I have:

```
var tempVar: NSString = ""

...

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
   if(segue.identifier == "second")
   {
       let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController
       secondVC.someVar = tempVar
   }
}

...

@IBAction func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
   tempVar = "someText"
   self.navigationController.pushViewController(self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondStoryBoardName") as secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code. Did you use performSegueWithIdentifier ?

Comment: Try this (in imagetapped) self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: self)

Comment: Thank you. This is work. Can you make answer I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in my comment:

Try this (in your imagetapped function)

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a choice.

---

If you want to / can link your two viewControllers with a segue, you must use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. Then, `prepareForSegue:sender:` will help you set your new viewController.

Your code with a segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
   if(segue.identifier == "second") {
       let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController
       secondVC.someVar = tempVar
   }
}

@IBAction func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   tempVar = "someText"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: nil)
    //No need to give your secondViewController an identifier ("secondStoryBoardName")
}
```

---

If you use `pushViewController:animated:`, it will not use any segue and the code in `prepareForSegue:sender:` won't be called.

Your code without a segue:

```
@IBAction func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   tempVar = "someText" 
   self.navigationController.pushViewController(self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondStoryBoardName") as secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```